# Embodied by vs. Embodied in

Tags: word-choice, verbs, idioms, phrasal-verbs

Give the correct passive form of - "My teacher embodies all the good qualities"

(a) All the good qualities are embodied by my teacher.

(b) All the good qualities are embodied in my teacher.

(c) All the good qualities are embodied with my teacher.

(d) All the good qualities are embodied to my teacher.

I found this question in a test. According to the exam setter, the correct answer is (b). Isn't (a) an acceptable answer as well?

---

[This might help you in answering the question](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embodied_INF%20by%2C%20embodied_INF%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cembodied_INF%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bembodied%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembody%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodies%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodying%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cembodied_INF%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bembodied%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembody%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodying%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodies%20in%3B%2Cc0#t3%3B%2Cembodied_INF%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bembodied%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembody%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodies%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodying%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cembodied_INF%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bembodied%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembody%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodying%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bembodies%20in%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  They can't be searched or indexed, and they're unfriendly to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a peculiar variation on English grammar.

Grammatically, “embodied by” uses the **typical** preposition of passive forms. However, other prepositions are allowed in passive forms.

> Bread is made from flour

> Bread is made with floor

> Bread is made in ovens

are sentences with perfectly good English grammar.

> Bread is made by flour

is not good English usage.

Of course,

> Bread is made by bakers

is good English.

“Embody” is a verb for which, as Ngram shows, “in” is the passive preposition blessed by usage.

Virtually by definition, “embody” incorporates the idea of non-physical abstractions being **exemplified** through something physical. Yet abstractions are not acts. The word “by” implies an actor. By using “in,” it is made clear that the abstract qualities are attributes of the preposition’s object rather than the results of actions taken by the preposition’s object.

Others may disagree, but I hesitate to call “embodied by” a mistake in grammar; it is a mistake in accepted usage.

Comment: "Others may disagree, but I hesitate to call “embodied by” a mistake in grammar; it is a mistake in accepted usage." - I didn't understand this sentence of yours fully. What do you think is the difference between a mistake in grammar and a mistake in accepted usage? Could you please elaborate on your last sentence a bit more?

Comment: What I am saying is that "by" in this case is one of the words that English uses in passive form verbs and "embodied by" would not be considered an egregious error, particularly in speech (which Ngram does not reflect).  However, "embodied by" is not a phrase that many skilled writers of English use. It marks the writer as not having a good ear for American or British writing. It is not a crime, but it is a blunder.